# Can one trisect the angle $\theta=\arccos(-12/17)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, proof-verification

I think this is not possible, and below is my proof.

Proof:

Using the angle tripling formula:
$$\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3 (\theta)−3\cos(\theta) \ \to \ \cos(\theta) = 4\cos^3 (\theta/3) -3\cos(\theta/3)$$  here $\cos(\theta) =-12/17$ so we have $4\cos^3 (\theta) -3\cos(\theta) =-12/17$. This implies $$68x^3-51x+12=0,\  x=\cos(\theta/3)$$
Hence $f(x)=68x^3-51x+12$ is a polynomial with root $\cos(\theta/3)$. Notice that $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial with this root by Eisenstein's criterion with $p=3$. Hence, $[\mathbb{Q}[\cos(\theta/3) ]:\mathbb{Q}]=3$ which is not a power of two.

Comment: Crypto - Please learn to use LaTeX, it will help other people understand your questions.

Comment: @nbubis, im trying man! I'm new to Latex.

Comment: The proof is fine.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks. I've only been asking all of these constructibility questions because I'm having a little trouble.

Comment: You are undoubtedly familiar with the proof that the $60^\circ$ angle is not trisectable, since your proof had basically the same structure. One could have used the Rational Roots Theorem instead of Eisenstein to prove irreducibility. More "elementary" but more work.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes, since the set r/s such that r|a_0 and s|a_n is not that large.

Answer (score 1):

Having solved the problem at hand, let us explore a more general result.

**Theorem**.  Suppose an angle $3\theta$ is given as the inverse cosine of a rational fraction expressed in lowest terms.  Then the trisected angle $\theta$ is constructible only if the denominator is a power of 2 times a cube.

Let $m/n$ be the given value of $\cos3\theta$ with $m,n$ relatively prime.  Then the cubic equation

$n\cos3\theta-m=4n\cos^3\theta-3n\cos\theta-m=0$

has constructible roots only if it has a rational root $p/q$ with $p,q$ relatively prime.  Then we must have

$\dfrac{m}{n}=4(\dfrac{p}{q})^3-3(\dfrac{p}{q})=\dfrac{4p^3-3pq^2}{q^3}$

Then $m/n$ in lowest terms implies

$n=q^3/\text{gcd}(4p^3-pq^2,q^3)$

Since $p$ is prime to $q$, the numerator cannot have any odd prime factors in common with $q$, so the quotient must have the same largest odd divisor as $q^3$.  The claimed result follows.

So $\cos3\theta=-12/17$ cannot be solved for $\theta$ by construction because $17$ is odd and not a cube.

The reader might note that the numerator is a multiple of $3$ in this problem.  If that's the case and the trisection is to be possible, then the reader is invited to prove that the numerator would also have to be a multiple of $9$.  No dice again for $\cos3\theta=-12/17$.